# csvsimple and siunitx

Tags: siunitx, csvsimple

I'm trying to import data from a csv file and using the `S` column type from `siunitx` to format the numbers with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{input_data.csv}
month, dogs, cats
January, 12.50,12.3e5
February, 3.32, 8.7e3
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\section{c}
\csvloop{
file=input_data.csv,
tabular={SS},
command=\csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
\end{document}
```

That gives me the following errors:

```
You can't use a prefix with `\hskip'. command=\csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
Missing number, treated as zero. command=\csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). command=\csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. command=\csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
Missing } inserted. command=\csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
```

If I change the first column to e.g. `c` it typesets.

I have found a workarund, by making an invisible column, but that feels quite ugly and I don't know if it have any side effects that I'm not aware of.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}}

\begin{filecontents*}{input_data.csv}
month, dogs, cats
January, 12.50,12.3e5
February, 3.32, 8.7e3
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\csvloop{
file=input_data.csv,
tabular={HSS},
command={}&\csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
\end{document}
```

So the question is if there is a more clean way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that having `S` as the first column type is not appreciated by `cvssimple`. But there are simpler ways for adding a dummy column and circumvent the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
month, dogs, cats
January, 12.50,12.3e5
February, 3.32, 8.7e3
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

X\csvloop{
file=\jobname.csv,
tabular={c@{}SS},
command=\empty & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii}X

\medskip

X\csvreader[
  tabular={c@{}SS},
]{\jobname.csv}{}{& \csvcolii & \csvcoliii}X

\medskip

X\begin{tabular}{SS}
12.50&12.3e5\\
3.32& 8.7e3
\end{tabular}X

\end{document}
```

The third tabular is “hand made”, just for comparison.

[image]

Comment: (+1) for that workaround. I have not stumbled upon this problem yet. It seems that the processing of an `S` column by `siuntix` is disturbed by the actions `csvsimple` does before each line. I would not know how to avoid this automatically.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Annoying, but not really difficult to work around. I didn't look at the internals; maybe you can add a caveat to the manual, if you're not able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another workaround. Instead of adding a dummy column, you could change the column type of the first column to `l`, `c` or `r`. The `siunitx` package provides a macro `\tablenum` which allows to format the numbers directly.

I use `egreg`'s method to display the code (the third table is for comparison):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
month, dogs, cats
January, 12.50,12.3e5
February, 3.32, 8.7e3
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

X\csvloop{
file=input_data.csv,
tabular={cS},
command=\tablenum{\csvcolii} & \csvcoliii}X

\medskip

X\csvloop{
file=input_data.csv,
tabular={cc},
command=\tablenum{\csvcolii} & \tablenum{\csvcoliii}}X

\medskip

X\begin{tabular}{SS}
12.50&12.3e5\\
3.32& 8.7e3
\end{tabular}X

\end{document}
```

[image]