# Last Column problem with csvsimple and siunitx

Tags: siunitx, csvsimple

I don't understand why it gives me the error `Extra }, or forgotten $. <recently read> }` in the part `...entoIdraulico & \RendimentoMeccanico } \\` if I change in `S` the last `c` of the part `\begin{tabular}{SS[table-format = 9.0]S[table-format = 9.0]S[table-format = 9.0]S[table-format = 1.4]c}`. Could someone explain me what I'm wrong or what should I do in order to solve that problem and have elements of the last column aligned by decimal separator?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,siunitx,csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{input.csv}
    Portata,PotenzaDisponibile,PotenzaIndicata,PotenzaMeccanica,RendimentoIdraulico,RendimentoMeccanico
    0,0,0,,0.7175,
    1,7840000,5849424,4049424,0.7461,0.692277393
    2,15680000,12112800,10312800,0.7725,0.851396869
    3,23520000,18738384,16938384,0.7967,0.903940489
    4,31360000,25674432,23874432,0.8187,0.929891341
    5,39200000,32869200,31069200,0.8385,0.945237487
    6,47040000,40270944,38470944,0.8561,0.955302761
    7,54880000,47827920,46027920,0.8715,0.962365079
    8,62720000,55488384,53688384,0.8847,0.967560778
    9,70560000,63200592,61400592,0.8957,0.971519254
    10,78400000,70912800,69112800,0.9045,0.974616712
    11,86240000,78573264,76773264,0.9111,0.977091444
    12,94080000,86130240,84330240,0.9155,0.979101417
    13,101920000,93531984,91731984,0.9177,0.980755246
    14,109760000,100726752,98926752,0.9177,0.982129872
    15,117600000,107662800,105862800,0.9155,0.983281133
    16,125440000,114288384,112488384,0.9111,0.984250368
    17,133280000,120551760,118751760,0.9045,0.985068654
    18,141120000,126401184,124601184,0.8957,0.985759627
    19,148960000,131784912,129984912,0.8847,0.98634138
    20,156800000,136651200,134851200,0.8715,0.986827778
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htp]
    \caption{Valori}
        \begin{tabular}{SS[table-format = 9.0]S[table-format = 9.0]S[table-format = 9.0]S[table-format = 1.4]c}
            \toprule
                \multirow{2}*{Portata} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Potenza} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Rendimento} \\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} & {Disponibile} & {Indicata} & {Meccanica} & {Idraulico} & {Meccanico} \\
                {(m\textsuperscript{3}/s)} & {(W)} & {(W)} & {(W)} & & %
                \csvreader[head to column names]{input.csv}{}{\\ \midrule \Portata & \PotenzaDisponibile & \PotenzaIndicata & \PotenzaMeccanica & \RendimentoIdraulico & \RendimentoMeccanico } \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> Also the answers for see [csvsimple and siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277096/csvsimple-and-siunitx)

There is some detection problem at the begin or end of a scanned line with `siunitx`. According to the table format, `siunitx` tries to detect the content of one cell for formatting. Unfortunately, there are also some invisible remains of the file reading process which seems to disturb the overall detection.

In your case, the last cell contains the problematic part. In my answer code, I change the place for `\\` to use some key setting features available, but the problem is just shifted to the first cell.

The real solution is to change the code for the problematic cell. Here, the first column is made `r` (could also be `l` or `c`) and the format is done inside the cell by

```
\tablenum{\Portata}
```

Now, `siunitx` only sees (and formats) what is should see.

[image]

The full code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,siunitx,csvsimple}


\begin{filecontents*}{input.csv}
    Portata,PotenzaDisponibile,PotenzaIndicata,PotenzaMeccanica,RendimentoIdraulico,RendimentoMeccanico
    0,0,0,,0.7175,
    1,7840000,5849424,4049424,0.7461,0.692277393
    2,15680000,12112800,10312800,0.7725,0.851396869
    3,23520000,18738384,16938384,0.7967,0.903940489
    4,31360000,25674432,23874432,0.8187,0.929891341
    5,39200000,32869200,31069200,0.8385,0.945237487
    6,47040000,40270944,38470944,0.8561,0.955302761
    7,54880000,47827920,46027920,0.8715,0.962365079
    8,62720000,55488384,53688384,0.8847,0.967560778
    9,70560000,63200592,61400592,0.8957,0.971519254
    10,78400000,70912800,69112800,0.9045,0.974616712
    11,86240000,78573264,76773264,0.9111,0.977091444
    12,94080000,86130240,84330240,0.9155,0.979101417
    13,101920000,93531984,91731984,0.9177,0.980755246
    14,109760000,100726752,98926752,0.9177,0.982129872
    15,117600000,107662800,105862800,0.9155,0.983281133
    16,125440000,114288384,112488384,0.9111,0.984250368
    17,133280000,120551760,118751760,0.9045,0.985068654
    18,141120000,126401184,124601184,0.8957,0.985759627
    19,148960000,131784912,129984912,0.8847,0.98634138
    20,156800000,136651200,134851200,0.8715,0.986827778
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htp]
    \caption{Valori}
        \begin{tabular}{rS[table-format = 9.0]S[table-format = 9.0]S[table-format = 9.0]S[table-format = 1.4]S[table-format = 1.9]}
            \toprule
                \multirow{2}*{Portata} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Potenza} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Rendimento} \\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} & {Disponibile} & {Indicata} & {Meccanica} & {Idraulico} & {Meccanico} \\
                {(m\textsuperscript{3}/s)} & {(W)} & {(W)} & {(W)} & & \\\midrule
                \csvreader[head to column names,late after line=\\\midrule,late after last line=\\\bottomrule]{input.csv}{}{%
                  \tablenum{\Portata} & \PotenzaDisponibile & \PotenzaIndicata & \PotenzaMeccanica & \RendimentoIdraulico & \RendimentoMeccanico
                }
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```