# csvsimple with siunitx S columns

Tags: siunitx, csvsimple

Similar to this: [csvsimple and siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277096/csvsimple-and-siunitx?rq=1)

Could there be a similar workaround but with `\csvlinetotablerow` instead of explicitly write every `\csvcoli`, `\csvcolii` ?

Here's my MWE :

```
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen]{standalone}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
A,B,C
1.23,4.5,67.89
1.2,34.56,7.89
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[
    tabular={SSS} % if I change it to {cSS}, it works flawlessly
]{data.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 2):

From the `csvsimple` document, page #50

> Special care is needed if the first or the last column is to be
> formatted with the column type S. The number detection of `siunitx` is
> disturbed by the line reading code of `csvsimple` which actually is
> present at the first and last column. To avoid this problem, the
> utilization of `\tablenum` is appropriate.
>
> Alternatively, a very nifty workaround suggested by Enrico Gregorio is
> to add an invisible dummy column with `c@{}` as first column and
> `@{}c` as last column.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[l3]{csvsimple}
\usepackage{siunitx}    

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    A,B,C
    1.23,4.5,67.89
    1.2,34.56,7.89
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.csv}
,A,B,C,
,1.23,4.5,67.89,
,1.2,34.56,7.89,
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    
    Using \verb|\tablenum|\bigskip
    
    \csvreader[
    head to column names,
    tabular={ccc} % 
    ]{data.csv}{}{\tablenum{\A} &\tablenum{\B}& \tablenum{\C}}
    
    \bigskip
    
    Using Enrico Gregorio suggestion    \bigskip
        
    \csvreader[
    head to column names,
    tabular={c@{}SSS@{}c} % 
    ]{data.csv}{}{&\A & \B & \C &}  \bigskip
    
    Now with \verb|\csvlinetotablerow| (different data set)\bigskip
        
    \csvreader[
    tabular={c@{}SSS@{}c} %
    ]{data2.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow}          

\end{document}
```

In a nutshell, to use `S` columns along with E.  Gregorio's suggestion and `\csvlinetotablerow`, an empty first and last column must be added to the original data set.